# Can MYSQL keep track of multiple Auto Increments based on a column input value?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table that has the base Auto Increment called `post_id`.  I have other columns as well, `tag_id`, and `tag_name`.

Currently, whenever I insert into this table, `post_id` will get auto incremented.  But what I also want to do is also auto increment `tag_id` depending on what `tag_name` is.  If `tag_name` is, for example, "`A`", then `tag_id` should be `1`.  Next insert, tag_name is "`A`" tag_id is `2`.  However, next insert, `tag_name` is "`B`", `tag_id` is now `1`.  etc, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both MyISAM and InnoDB support only one auto-increment per table.

Managing any autoincrement-per-group feature cannot work in a storage engine that supports concurrent updates, because of race conditions.

MyISAM supports [auto-increment as a secondary column of a key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html), so it numbers independently for each value in the first column of the same key. But this still won't work for you because MyISAM doesn't support two auto columns per table.

```
mysql> create table MyTable (
    -> post_id int auto_increment primary key,
    -> tag_name varchar(10),
    -> tag_id int auto_increment,
    -> unique key (tag_name, tag_id)
    -> ) engine=myisam;
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one
auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

You'll have to number your tag_id manually. And that means you can't support concurrent updates to this table.

IMO, you should re-think what you're trying to do.